# Checkable groupbox element for HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Is there a way to reach functionality as in example below?

Example:

[image]

You could check 'Validity', and it will pass extra values on listed inputs inside this groupbox when the form will be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind a JavaScript function to the "change" event on the checkbox that sets the "disabled" property of the inputs. Disabled inputs won't be submitted.